# Clearing only specific html tags (with or without attributes) from text using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, html-parsing

Say I have the following html as text / string:

```
<html>
  <a><span>some text</span></a>
  <a attr='attr_value'><b>Some bold text</b></a>
<html>
```

How can I remove all the `<a></a>` tags ONLY (with or without attributes) such that I will get the following result:

```
<html>
  <span>some text</span>
  <b>Some bold text</b>
<html>
```

Pure javascript please (no JQuery), maybe replace + regex (?)

Comment: Create a documentFragment, append your string to the fragment, delete links, and create a new string from the fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the following regex to remove the `<a>` tags:

```
/</?a[^>]*>/
```

- `/ ... /` - the regex delimeters
- `< ... >` - matches the start and end of the tag itself
- `/?` - matches an optional "/" to handle the beginning of a closing tag
- `a` - makes sure that you've captured an `<a>` tag
- `[^<]*` - matches zero or more of any character that does not close the tag

Since the HTML `<a>` tag has to close before you can begin another HTML tag, you can use the of the "not a greater than sign" pattern (`[^>]`) to match any characters inside the tag.

Set it up as a regex variable first, or include it inline in the replace:

```
var regexATagPattern = new RegExp("</?a[^>]*>", "g");
var new_string = some_string.replace(regexATagPattern, "");
```

. . . or . . .

```
var new_string = some_string.replace(/<\/?a[^>]*>/g, "");
```

(Note the differences in how the pattern is created between the two approaches.)

**Note:** The **ONLY** situation where you could run into an issue would be it you have an attribute with a string value that included an escaped ">" in it.  If this is a concern, then you'd have to get a lot more complicated.

Comment: thanks, it works perfectly. Great and inspiring answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be:

```
str.replace(/(<a>)|(<a attr='attr_value'>)|(<\/a>)/g, "");
```

I think my rgx is correct, but if no try to use http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: (<a>)|(<a )([0-9a-zA-Z\W])+(=')([0-9a-zA-Z_\W ])+('>)|(<\/a>)
regxp for attributes and attributes value